# Stack space overflow error while running recursive compiled code. Fine tune algorithm, or give more resources?

Tags: haskell

I am working on project [Euler #14](http://projecteuler.net/problem=14), and have a solution to get the answer, but am getting a stack space overflow error when I try to run the code. The algorithm works OK in the interactive GHCI (on low numbers), but wont work when I throw a really big number at it and try to compile it.

Here is a rough idea of what it does in the interactive GHCI. It takes about 10 seconds to calculate "answer 50000" on my computer.

After letting GHCI run the problem for a few minutes, it spits out the correct answer.

```
*Euler System.IO> answer 1000000
    (525,837799)
```

But that doesn't solve the stack overflow error when compiling the program to run natively.

```
*Euler System.IO> answer 10
    (20,9)
*Euler System.IO> answer 100
    (119,97)
*Euler System.IO> answer 1000
    (179,871)
*Euler System.IO> answer 10000
    (262,6171)
*Euler System.IO> answer 50000
    (324,35655)
```

What should I do to get the answer to for "answer 1000000"? I imagine my algorithm needs to be fine tuned a bit, but I have no idea how to go about doing that.

Code:

```
module Main
    where

import System.IO
import Control.Monad

main = print (answer 1000000)

-- Count the length of the sequences
-- count' creates a tuple with the second value
-- being the starting number of the game
-- and the first value being the total 
-- length of the chain
count' n = (cSeq n, n)
cSeq n = length $ game n

-- Find the maximum chain value of the game
answer n = maximum $ map count' [1..n]

-- Working game. 
-- game 13 = [13,40,20,10,5,16,8,4,2,1]
game n = n : play n
play x
    | x <= 0 = []                               -- is negative or 0
    | x == 1 = []                               -- is 1
    | even x = doEven x : play ((doEven x))     -- even
    | otherwise = doOdd x : play ((doOdd x))    -- odd
  where doOdd x = (3 * x) + 1
        doEven  x = (x `div` 2)
```

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled? I suspect `maximum` may be the culprit here (it's often too lazy). Try with `foldl1' max` instead of `maximum`.

Comment: `foldl1 max` gives the same error

Comment: `foldl1'`, not `foldl1`. The apostrophe is important, as it's the strict version.

Comment: Note that this problem is really about memoization, you should memoize the length of the cycle for each number you test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `maximum` is too lazy. Instead of keeping track of the largest element as it goes along, it builds up a huge tree of `max` thunks. This is because `maximum` is defined in terms of `foldl`, so the evaluation goes as follows:

```
maximum [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
foldl max 1 [2, 3, 4, 5]
foldl max (max 1 2) [3, 4, 5]
foldl max (max (max 1 2) 3) [4, 5]
foldl max (max (max (max 1 2) 3) 4) [5]
foldl max (max (max (max (max 1 2) 3) 4) 5) []
max (max (max (max 1 2) 3) 4) 5  -- this expression will be huge for large lists
```

Trying to evaluate too many of these nested `max` calls causes a stack overflow.

The solution is to force it to evaluate these as it goes along by using the strict version `foldl'`, (or, in this case, its cousin `foldl1'`). This prevents the `max`'s from building up by reducing them at each step:

```
foldl1' max [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
foldl' max 1 [2, 3, 4, 5]
foldl' max 2 [3, 4, 5]
foldl' max 3 [4, 5]
foldl' max 4 [5]
foldl' max 5 []
5
```

GHC can often solve these kinds of problems on its own if you compile with `-O2` which (among other things) runs a strictness analysis of your program. However, I think it's good practice to write programs that don't need to rely on optimizations to work.

<sub>**Note:** After fixing this, the resulting program is still very slow. You might want to look into using memoization for this problem.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

@hammar already [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12742166/1011995) the problem that `maximum` is too lazy, and how to resolve that (using `foldl1'`, the strict version of `foldl1`).

But there are further inefficiencies in the code.

```
cSeq n = length $ game n
```

`cSeq` lets `game` construct a list, only to calculate its length. Unfortunately, `length` is not a "good consumer", so the construction of the intermediate list is not fused away. That's quite a bit of unnecessary allocation and costs time. Eliminating these lists

```
cSeq n = coll (1 :: Int) n
  where
    coll acc 1 = acc
    coll acc m
      | even m    = coll (acc + 1) (m `div` 2)
      | otherwise = coll (acc + 1) (3*m+1)
```

cuts down the allocation by something like 65% and the running time by about 20% (still slow).  Next point, you're using `div`, which performs a sign check in addition to the normal division. Since all numbers involved are positive, using `quot` instead does speed it up a bit more (not much here, but it will become important later).

The next big point is that, since you haven't given type signatures, the type of the numbers (except where it was determined by the use of `length` or by the expression type signature `(1 :: Int)` in my rewrite) is `Integer`. The operations on `Integer` are considerably slower than the corresponding operations on `Int`, so if possible, you should use `Int` (or `Word`) rather than `Integer` when speed matters. If you have a 64-bit GHC, `Int` is sufficient for these computations, that reduces the running time by about half when using `div`, by about 70% when using `quot`, when using the native code generator, and when using the LLVM backend, the running time is reduced by about 70% when using `div` and by about 95% when using `quot`.

The difference between the native code generator and the LLVM backend is mostly due to some elementary low-level optimisations.

`even` and `odd` are defined

```
even, odd       :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool
even n          =  n `rem` 2 == 0
odd             =  not . even
```

in `GHC.Real`. When the type is `Int`, LLVM knows to replace the division by 2 used to determine the modulus with a bitwise and (`n .&. 1 == 0`). The native code generator does not (yet) do many of these low-level optimisations. If you do that by hand, the code produced by the NCG and the LLVM backend performs nearly identically.

When using `div`, both, the NCG and LLVM, are not able to replace the division with a short shift-and-add sequence, so you get the relatively slow machine division instruction with the sign-test. With `quot`, both are able to do that for `Int`, so you get much faster code.

The knowledge that all occurring numbers are positive allows us to replace the division by 2 with a simple right shift, without any code to correct for negative arguments, that speeds up the code produced by the LLVM backend by another ~33%, oddly it doesn't make a difference for the NCG.

So from the original that took eight second plus/minus a bit (a little less with the NCG, a little more with the LLVM backend), we've gone to

```
module Main (main)
    where

import Data.List
import Data.Bits

main = print (answer (1000000 :: Int))

-- Count the length of the sequences
-- count' creates a tuple with the second value
-- being the starting number of the game
-- and the first value being the total 
-- length of the chain
count' n = (cSeq n, n)
cSeq n = go (1 :: Int) n
  where
    go !acc 1 = acc
    go acc m
        | even' m   = go (acc+1) (m `shiftR` 1)
        | otherwise = go (acc+1) (3*m+1)

even' :: Int -> Bool
even' m = m .&. 1 == 0

-- Find the maximum chain value of the game
answer n = foldl1' max $ map count' [1..n]
```

which takes 0.37 seconds with the NCG, and 0.27 seconds with the LLVM backend on my setup.

A minute improvement in running time, but a huge reduction of allocation can be obtained by replacing the `foldl1' max` with a manual recursion,

```
answer n = go 1 1 2
  where
    go ml mi i
        | n < i     = (ml,mi)
        | l > ml    = go l i (i+1)
        | otherwise = go ml mi (i+1)
          where
            l = cSeq i
```

that makes it 0.35 resp. 0.25 seconds (and produces a tiny `52,936 bytes allocated in the heap`).

Now if that is still too slow, you can worry about a good memoisation strategy. The best I know<sup>(1)</sup> is to use an unboxed array to store the chain lengths for the numbers not exceeding the limit,

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main (main) where

import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Base
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Bits

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let bd = case args of
               a:_ -> read a
               _   -> 100000
    print $ mxColl bd

mxColl :: Int -> (Int,Int)
mxColl bd = runST $ do
    arr <- newArray (0,bd) 0
    unsafeWrite arr 1 1
    goColl arr bd 1 1 2

goColl :: STUArray s Int Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> ST s (Int,Int)
goColl arr bd ms ml i
    | bd < i    = return (ms,ml)
    | otherwise = do
        nln <- collatzLength arr bd i
        if ml < nln
          then goColl arr bd i nln (i+1)
          else goColl arr bd ms ml (i+1)

collatzLength :: STUArray s Int Int -> Int -> Int -> ST s Int
collatzLength arr bd n = go 1 n
  where
    go !l 1 = return l
    go l m
        | bd < m    = go (l+1) $ case m .&. 1 of
                                   0 -> m `shiftR` 1
                                   _ -> 3*m+1
        | otherwise = do
            l' <- unsafeRead arr m
            case l' of
              0 -> do
                  l'' <- go 1 $ case m .&. 1 of
                                  0 -> m `shiftR` 1
                                  _ -> 3*m+1
                  unsafeWrite arr m (l''+1)
                  return (l + l'')
              _ -> return (l+l'-1)
```

which does the job for a limit of 1000000 in 0.04 seconds when compiled with the NCG, 0.05 with the LLVM backend (apparently, that is not as good at optimising `STUArray` code as the NCG is).

If you don't have a 64-bit GHC, you can't simply use `Int`, since that would overflow then for some inputs.
But the overwhelming part of the computation is still performed in `Int` range, so you should use that where possible and only move to `Integer` where required.

```
switch :: Int
switch = (maxBound - 1) `quot` 3

back :: Integer
back = 2 * fromIntegral (maxBound :: Int)

cSeq :: Int -> Int
cSeq n = goInt 1 n
  where
    goInt acc 1      = acc
    goInt acc m
      | m .&. 1 == 0 = goInt (acc+1) (m `shiftR` 1)
      | m > switch   = goInteger (acc+1) (3*toInteger m + 1)
      | otherwise    = goInt (acc+1) (3*m+1)
    goInteger acc m
      | fromInteger m .&. (1 :: Int) == 1 = goInteger (acc+1) (3*m+1)
      | m > back  = goInteger (acc+1) (m `quot` 2)  -- yup, quot is faster than shift for Integer here
      | otherwise = goInt (acc + 1) (fromInteger $ m `quot` 2)
```

makes it harder to optimise the loop(s), so it is slower than the single loop using `Int`, but still decent. Here (where the `Integer` loop is never run), it takes 0.42 seconds with the NCG and 0.37 with the LLVM backend (which is pretty much the same as using `quot` in the pure `Int` version).

Using a similar trick for the memoised version has similar consequences, it's considerably slower than the pure `Int` version, but still blazingly fast compared to unmemoised versions.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> For this special (type of) problem, where you need to memoise the results for a contiguous range of arguments. For other problems, a `Map` or some other data structure will be the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `maximum` function is the culprit as already pointed out, but you shouldn't have to worry about it if you compile your program with the `-O2` flag.

The program is still quite slow, this is because the problem is supposed to teach you about memoization. One good way of doing this is haskell is by using `Data.Memocombinators`:

```
import Data.MemoCombinators
import Control.Arrow
import Data.List
import Data.Ord
import System.Environment

play m = maximumBy (comparing snd) . map (second threeNPuzzle) $ zip [1..] [1..m]
  where
    threeNPuzzle = arrayRange (1,m) memoized
    memoized n 
      | n == 1 = 1
      | odd n  = 1 + threeNPuzzle (3*n + 1)
      | even n = 1 + threeNPuzzle (n `div` 2)

main = getArgs >>= print . play . read . head
```

The above program runs in under a second when compiled with `-O2` on my machine.

Note that in this case it is not a good idea to memoize all values found by threeNPuzzle, the program above memoizes the ones up until the limit (1000000 in the problem).